# $().contents().outerHeight() doesn't get the correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to resize an `iframe` with the content height of the inner web page in this way:

```
<iframe
    src="hi.com"
    width="100%" onload="resizeIframe();" scrolling="no"
    frameborder="0" />

function resizeIframe() {
    $('iframe').height(  $('iframe').contents().outerHeight() );
}
```

The problem is that when the `resizeIframe()` function is executed is getting a lower value than the actual height.

My intuition tells me that the inner web is not loaded completely when I execute the function.

If I do it with `setInterval(resizeIframe, 100);` this works properly, but I don't want to use timers for this.

I have tried to with
`$('#idGFRt').ready( $('iframe').height(  $('iframe').contents().outerHeight() ));`
but this makes me the same that first case.

***(idGFRt is the id of the inner web form)***

The question is:

1 - Is this produced because the inner web is not completely loaded?

2 - If so, how can I control that the inner web is loaded before set the iframe height?

Comment: consider a plugin? https://github.com/wistful/jquery-iframe-auto-height

if the content change does the iframe? a plugin will sort it

Comment: Is the iframe page loading content asynchronously using javascript?

Comment: Any console errors, like cross domain errors?

Comment: are you trying to do it from the containing page, the one with the iframe or the doc inside the iframe?

two totally different solutions

Comment: @charlietfl no, it isn't

Comment: @mplungjan no problems with cross domain

Comment: @jenson-button-event the page inside the "iframe" is from a separate web application. I'm trying to do it from my own application, I have no control over the code of the other app.

Comment: You can't access inside a cross domain iframe due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: @charlietfl I think I'm not having that problem, I have the content of the "iframe" but with about 500 pixels less and if I set 50 milliseconds in setInterval(), I get the completely content.

Comment: so something in the script in that page is likely changing the height. There is no magic way to know what that is

Comment: @charlietfl Is there any way to know when it has finished executing the javascript functions that modify the height in the inner page? Maybe any JS is producing the problem.

Comment: Not without knowing what that script is or what it does. You could use a setInterval to keep checking for a few seconds until height stabilizes